# How do I disable Tab Groups in Edge?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge, tab-groups

Edge recently got updated on my Windows 10, and now I can't find how to disable Tab Groups anymore. These are the only two options I see now:

[image]

I have read the instructions available online, many of which mentioned edge://flags/#tab-groups. I don't see the option to disable Tab Groups. Only the two shown above. How can I disable this feature now?

I have managed to disable Tab Groups on other machines. Something is broken on this one but I don't know what. I have done "Repair" on Microsoft Edge installation. That did nothing. Not sure what else I can do.

EDIT: I have tried a full clean reinstall of Windows by making a new installation media, using the Windows Media Creation Tool. Yup, all good. The Tab Groups flag was available again! I disabled it, and confirmed it was disabled. Then Edge got updated. And, that option is gone again! Not only that, but now Tab Groups is enabled again. Edge is currently at Version 99.0.1150.39 (Official build) (64-bit).

Comment: Seems they removed the ability to disable a very annoying totally pointless feature that seems to annoy everybody. Nice one MS. This is why I'm going to Brave....

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension for this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-close-tab-groups/cfbnfkpaoldidigecaidbidijnhbgbll

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Robert, as ot stands, your answer could be considered spammy. Try editing it and describe the software. Give a screenshot perhaps.